# no internet on LAN, pfsense

Tags: networking, virtualbox, pfsense

i have installed pfSense 2.2 in virtualbox on my windows7 laptop. WAN(em0) interface is assigned to wireless adapter of the laptop and LAN(em1) interface is assigned to lan adapter of the laptop.

LAN(em1) has dhcp enabled. Another guest(xp, lan adapter of laptop as its lan inteface) is getting ip from LAN(em1) dhcp.

i can ping WAN(em0) IP and LAN(em1) IP from XP but cant ping outsied. XP is not getting internet.

can anyone plz help over this? I am very new to pfSens.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:i removed and installed pfSense and all's fine

Comment: What do you mean? You just reinstalled it?